# display data of specific/current/ logged in user in firebase cloud

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

anyone can you give your opinion about this kind structure in Firestore?

I want to display the data of current logged in user.
Let's say i have some users in my app:

I want the Query like that firebaseFirestore.collection("Complaints").document(user_id).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener()

**This is my code:**

firebaseFirestore.collection("Complaints").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

```
            for (DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
            {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                {
                    Complaints complaints = doc.getDocument().toObject(Complaints.class);
                    complaintsList.add(complaints);

                    complaintsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is a good structure

```
Users
 - userID
    - User Info
    - User Roles (if using role based authorization)

Other Data Collections
 - Other Data Documents
    - Other Sub Collections
```

Comment: Sir kindly now again check my question. I edited my question

Comment: What are you asking now? It seems like you know what you want now...

Comment: Sir I am asking that how I can retrieve the data of current logged In user in recyclerView from FirebaseFirestore

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Here the data is data will be  added only once by addOnCompleteListener. I want the data will be real time by addSnapshot event Listener...I want to do like this mFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).addSnapshot

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen - realtime updates documentation

Comment: Thank you, its really help full